# python: how to use dictionary and for loop to work out total cost for a list of (item, quantity) tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, tuples

this is my first time using stack overflow as I am just starting to learn python so apologies if I don't phrase things as clearly as I should!

I am working on a problem which asks me to set up a stationery shop. There is a dictionary with prices:

```py
stationery_prices = {
    'pen': 0.55,
    'pencil': 1.55,
    'rubber': 2.55,
    'ruler': 3.55
}
```

I have to ask the user to input what item they would like and what quantity, and then arrange this in a list of tuples.

So now I have a list that looks like this:

```py
[('pen', 1), ('pencil', 2)]
```

How do I use a for loop to refer back to the original dictionary of prices and add up the total cost for the user?

Thank you very much

Comment: for loop through your list and for each item, do `stationary_prices.get(item[0]) * item[1]` and add the result to an ongoing sum variable

Comment: You should correct your example list (e.g. pens, pencils) in example vs. pen, pencil in stationery_prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over each element, unpacking the tuple:

```py
total = 0
for bought_item in bought_items:
    item_name = bought_item[0]
    quantity = bought_item[1]
    total += stationery_prices[item_name] * quantity

print(total)
```

Note that this is more verbose than necessary (e.g. no tuple unpacking in the `for` loop). I chose to do this to reduce possible confusion with unfamiliar syntax. If you wanted to do it in one line, you could do:

```py
total = sum(stationery_prices[item_name] * quantity 
    for item_name, quantity in bought_items)
```

Comment: hello ! thank you very much this was very helpful. when i try to put it into my code i get an error on the += line, would you mind explaining how the item name retrieves the price from the dictionary using the [:-1]  part? thank you !

Comment: The question as originally posted contained the plural form of each item; the `[:-1]` chopped off the `'s'` at the end of each word to make it singular.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect this change; you don't need to slice off the last character anymore, so you can remove the slicing entirely.

Comment: thank you so much !! i really appreciate it :) sorry - the original plurals were a mistake